# Como fazer uma função para calcular e alertar o número de lâmpadas necessárias para iluminar um determinado cômodo

Tags: javascript, html, funções

```
function alertarNumeroDeLampadas(){
              var potencia = prompt ("Digite o valor da potência da lâmpada em watts: ");
              var largura = prompt ("Digite o valor da largura do local(Metros): ");
              var comprimento = prompt ("Digite o valor do comprimento do local(Metros): ");
              resultado = (largura*comprimento)/potencia;
              return resultado;
            }
            alert(alertarNumeroDeLampadas());
```

Não estou conseguindo chegar no resultado.Alguém pode me ajudar ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o problema? o que está acontecendo e o que deveria acontecer?

Comment: Que matemática eu tenho que fazer para chegar no numero de lampada ?

Comment: você precisa considerar a sua constante que é de pelo menos 18W por m², aí saberá quantas lampadas são necessárias.

Comment: Embora do modo como foi feita a pergunta a duvida seja na operação matemática, não resta duvida que seja um bom exercício de funções em javascript (entradas via prompt e não numericas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O cálculo deve ser feito dessa forma:

```
var potenciaTotal = (largura * comprimento) * 18;
var resultado = potenciaTotal / potencia;
```

Segue exemplo:

```js
function alertarNumeroDeLampadas(){
  var potencia = prompt("Digite o valor da potência da lâmpada em watts:");
  var largura = prompt("Digite o valor da largura do local(Metros):");
  var comprimento = prompt ("Digite o valor do comprimento do local(Metros):");
  
  var potenciaTotal = (largura * comprimento) * 18;
  var resultado = potenciaTotal / potencia;

  return resultado;
}
console.log(alertarNumeroDeLampadas());
```

Comment: Essa parte eu ja tinha em mente de como fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo, ainda seria necessário colocar os tratamentos para validação dos inputs, mas como a questão deve ser para validar a lógica... esse exemplo cumpre os requisitos.

```js
function alertarNumeroDeLampadas() {

  //potência mínima requisitada por m²
  var potenciaMinima = 18;

  var potencia = prompt("Digite o valor da potência da lâmpada em watts: ");
  var largura = prompt("Digite o valor da largura do local(Metros): ");
  var comprimento = prompt("Digite o valor do comprimento do local(Metros): ");

  //resultado total da potência por m² obtida com a parametrização
  resultado = (largura * comprimento) / potencia;

  //Math.ceil() para arrendondar para cima, porque não existe meia lâmpada...
  return Math.ceil(resultado * potenciaMinima);
}

alert(alertarNumeroDeLampadas());
```

Comment: As entradas não devem aceitar valores não numéricos

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, boa observação, poste a resposta com o tratamento de entradas, incluíndo as validações e desvios de fluxo para o tratamento.

Answer (score 1):

Atualizada em 19/03/2018 11:19:00

- Com os tratamentos para validação dos inputs
- Com alerta avisando caso entrada seja invalida
- Caso em qualquer prompt seja clicado o botão cancelado a operação é cancelada

```js
 function numLampadas() {
 
  function alerta(){
     alert("entrada invalida!");
  }
  
  var larg = (function l() {
    largura = prompt('Digite o valor da largura do local(Metros):');
    if (isNaN(largura)||largura==""){ 
      alerta();
     l();
    }
  }());
  
  if (largura == null){
    alert("operação cancelada");
  }else{
    var comp = (function c() { 
      comprimento = prompt ("Digite o valor do comprimento do local(Metros): ");
      if (isNaN(comprimento)||comprimento==""){ 
        alerta();
       c();
      }
    }());
  
    if (comprimento == null){
      alert("operação cancelada");
    }else{
      var pot = (function p() {  
        potenciaLampada = prompt ("Digite o valor da potência da lâmpada em watts: ");
        if (isNaN(potenciaLampada)||potenciaLampada==""){ 
         alerta();
         p();
        }
      }());
  
      if (potenciaLampada == null){
        alert("operação cancelada");
      }else{
        resultado = "Numero de lampadas necessárias = "+(largura*comprimento*18)/potenciaLampada;
        alert(resultado);
        var labe1= document.getElementById('labe1');
 
           labe1.innerText  = "Novo cálculo";
    
      }
    
    }
  
  }
 }
```

```html
<button id="labe1" onclick="numLampadas()">Iniciar cálculo</button>
```

Comment: +1, tem como adicionar um `alert()` para informar o usuário que a entrada era inválida e por isso ele precisa informar novamente?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, faça uma função alerta e chame-a antes das funções l() c() e p()

Comment: Boa!, se pudesse eu dava +1 de novo :)